# Paste from word with uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I pasted text from Word into the CKEditor javascript library. Some part of this text is uppercase in Word.

When the "Paste From Word" popup appear, the text is correctly formatted (with uppercase) but if I inspect the element the text is wrapped in a `<span style="text-transform:uppercase">`.

Then when I click "Ok" the text is copied in the CKEditor field but it removes the `<span>` and my text is now lowercase.

Is it possible to preserve the uppercase ? Either by not removing the span or by converting the span to uppercase ?

Comment: You may get better help for this on another StackExchange site such as www.superuser.com

Comment: Why ? That's a javascript library

Comment: what library is this ?

Comment: CKEditor, it's a javascript addon to edit html into an html webpage.

Comment: You might want to look into the `config` of your editor; here's a solid start: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles

Comment: I don't get why all of you are confused. This question is super clear. If you don't know the library, just don't vote and don't comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to preserve that `span`. It is removed because none of enabled CKEditor features does not allow for this style. However, you can extend the Advanced Content Filter which is responsible for filtering with your own rules:

```
// Allow span with text-transform style.
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span{!text-transform}';
```

You may also need to disable one of [`pasteFromWord*`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordRemoveStyles) options:

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
```

Remeber to clear cache after changing `config.js`!

PS. It is also possible to transform text in that span to upper case and remove the span, but it would require some custom coding in [`CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor)'s [filters](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your PS is even more better. At first, I thought I would have to leave the tags there and transform the tags on the back-end. I will look into your link and try to code something in CKEditor.